# Interference between 27MHz RX and 5.8GHz TX

Tags: rf, remote-control

I've got a 27MHz RC car and 5.8GHz Fat Shark video transmitter. When I drive the RC car using the video transmitter, it seems to lose signal from the 27MHz remote at a pretty close distance, say 2-3m through a wooden wall. When I turn the transmitting off and drive blindly in the same circumstances, everything seems OK. What can I do to improve the communication? Max range I'd hope for is 5-7m, and both components of my setup seem to work at this distance independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interference might be caused due to non-rf components too.. e.g. power lines. Or, your Video-Tx might be eating a lot of power from battery causing voltages to drop somewhat (less likely)

Do you observe drop in range even when video tx is on, but not mounted on car?

Try separating Video + Video-Tx system from the rest by powering it from a different battery.

Also, keep video-Tx antenna as far away from RC-Rx antenna as physically possible.

Comment: It's already powered by another battery =) I'll try to separate antennas and see if it works.

Comment: Awesome! I moved Video TX to the front of the car, disassembled it and moved RC-RX antenna to the rear. Range increased dramatically compared to what it was before with the TX too close to the RX. Thank you for your help!